# Why causes an image to exceed the bounds of the image view when a label has the text changed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Not sure how to concisely ask this question. I have an image that is animated. The image starts at 200x200, shrinks to 0x0, then enlarges back to 200x200. I am using a slider to set the animationDuration of the image. I am using the same slider to set the text of a label with the value selected by the slider, e.g. if the slider is set to 3, then the label displays 3.00.

The issue is that when the text for the label is set after the slider is moved, the image will start the animation sequence at some value greater than 200x200. If I comment out the code that sets the text of the label, I can still change the animation speed of the image and it remains in the bounds I set.

Here is the ViewController.m file:

```
import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

- (IBAction)animate:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)stopAnimate:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController
//global variables:
//height and width
float h, w;

//boolean to set default animation status
bool isAnimated = YES;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

//set w and h to the width and height of the image, respectively
w = _image.bounds.size.width;
h = _image.bounds.size.height;


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)numSliderValueChange:(id)sender {
    //when the user moves the slider, show the new value in the lable
    [_lblAnimationDuration setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [_numSlider value]]];
}

- (IBAction)animate:(id)sender {
    //keeps the image animated until stop is clicked
    isAnimated = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[_numSlider value] delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        CGRect rect = _image.bounds;

        //set w (h) to the difference of the bounds of the rect and the image w (h)
        rect.size.width = w - rect.size.width;
        rect.size.height = h - rect.size.height;

        //assign rect to the image bounds
        _image.bounds = rect;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            if (isAnimated) {
                [self animate:sender];
            }
        }
    }];
}

- (IBAction)stopAnimate:(id)sender {
    //changes isAnimated to NO when "Stop" is clicked, stopping the image's animation
    isAnimated = NO;
}

@end
```

When the label text is changed, the image will expand to about halfway down the app for one animation cycle. Otherwise, the size of the image never exceeds what you see in the pic.

[image: Image should never be larger than this]

Comment: Are you using autolayout to position the image view in Interface Builder?

Comment: @dan yes. Constrained it to be vertically centered

Comment: do you mean Image does not animate at all? or it animate to 100x100 and not srinking to 0x0?

Comment: @JasmeetKaur It animates. If you move the slider, instead of starting at 200x200, the image starts the animation at about 300x300, covering the buttons and the label. But it only does it for one animation cycle. After the first cycle where it gets too big, it will behave as expected, until you move the slider again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AutoLayout, I suggest you modify the size of your `image` using layout property by setting NSLayoutConstraint for width and height of your `image`

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *width;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *height;
```

To use the properties above, you have to add height and width constraint for your `image` in your xib then connect this two properties.

You can then use these constraints to change your image size by:

```
self.width.constant = yourNewValue
```